# multiple arg.names barplot

Tags: r, label, bar-chart, names

im trying to label my stacked barplot correctly and would like to add additional names to every 2 "bars".
Here is what i got so far:

This is my "counts" table for drawing the bars (i'm sorry i don't know a better way to link the data):

`1 1.5  2 2.5  3 3.5
  M8244  0  20  0  16  0   4
  cp14  20   0 16   0  5   0
  cp17   0   0  0   0  1   0
  cp4    0   0  0   0  1   0`

and my code:

`barplot(counts, main="deadwood isolates",
        xlab="sampling timepoint", ylab="samples obtained",ylim=c(0,21),
        col=c("grey85","white","grey40","black"),space=c(1,0),
        names.arg=c("fungus","CHV-1","fungus","CHV-1","fungus","CHV-1"),
        offset=0,mgp=c(4,1,0)
        )
legend = rownames(counts)
legend("topright",legend,fill=c("grey85","white","grey40","black"))`

I cheated a bid using 1.5, 2.5, 3.5 in the data input to be able to group the bars since using `beside` its not possible to get stacked barplots.
I would like to label the grouped bars (1&1.5 ; 2&2.5 ; 3&3.5) with something like "timepoint1" "timepoint2" and "timepoint3" below the present names (fungus/CHV-1).
Is that possible? 
Thank you already in advance for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "\n" for the new line.

```
line1 <- c("fungus","CHV-1","fungus","CHV-1","fungus","CHV-1")
line2 <- paste0("timepoint", 1:6)
vector_names.arg <- paste(line1, line2, sep = "\n")
```